# how can I make a discord bot in python detect if another bot is running

Tags: discord.py

I'd like to see how to make a discord bot written using discord.py can detect if another python-made discord bot is running

I have no clue where to start and just want some help.

Comment: This is way too broad of a question. This site is best used if you can post a minimal reproducible example for specific places you're stuck or looking for help.

Comment: What do you mean with "detect if another python bot is running"? On the same machine? In the same Discord server?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really broad question, however if you would like to see if a discord user is a bot or not you can look at the `discord.User.bot`

Here's [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User.bot) for this attribute.

There is no way built into the discord API to find out explicitly what language a bot has been written in.